# API :urn/metadata/:guid/properties response "Too large the size of properties JSON, please call this API with query by object id"

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

On 01/11/2021 we noticed that most of the requests with forceget :urn/metadata/:guid/properties began to respond with 406 error 'diagnostic: "Too large the size of properties JSON, please call this API with query by object id"', although the models are not big.
Everything was good before.
I tried adding query objectid but the result was the same.
I didn't find anything about this in сhangelog. Maybe something happened?

Comment: Our apology for late response! he escalation with autodesk-forge tag stopped working for a while. We just noticed your post. Regarding  with the error you have, I vaguely remember some other customers also reported around that date. After that, it started to be working. Could you check if this issue still exists? Please do let us know if it is not working